# How Haskell linking may work given that STG generates custom ABI

Tags: haskell, ghc

As far as I understand,code generated from STG uses very custom ABI, which even has custom call stack.

How linker does work then? Does GHC use custom linker?

Comment: Why should linker know anything about calling conventions and such? It just substitutes symbol names with offsets/addresses.

Comment: If you are literally asking about the linker, I think the existing answer is great. But I think it's also possible you are asking about the linker accidentally, and are actually interested more broadly in the FFI and how interop with other languages works. Is that the case?

Comment: @DanielWagner No. As far as I understand, FFI calls external code, which has standart ABI convention, so this situation looks clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `ghc` with the `-v` flag to generate verbose logging output, you'll see that it invokes `gcc` to perform the final link.  Of course, `gcc` uses the standard system `ld` linker, but with some additional setup that GHC finds useful.

As mentioned by @arrowd in the comments, the linker doesn't really care much about calling conventions.  For the most part, it just fixes up undefined references to symbols in other object files, whether those symbols reference code or data.

When a Haskell module is compiled to native code, it mostly takes the form of a bunch of data structures ("closures") and code snippets prefixed with metadata ("info blocks"), and that data and code is labelled with global symbols, which can be referenced by other modules and resolved by the linker, the same way references to data structures or C functions might be resolved when linking a C program.

As a simple example, the rather silly module:

```
module Foo where

foo :: (a -> b -> c) -> d -> a -> b -> c
foo f = const f
```

when compiled with `ghc -c -O0 -fforce-recomp -ddump-asm Foo.hs` generates basically the following info block and closure for `foo` (simplified by removing some extra assembly pragmas).

```
;; info block, proceeded by a few quad words of metadata
.section .text
    .quad   4294967301
    .quad   0
    .long   14
    .long   GHC.Base.const_closure-(Foo.foo_info)+0
Foo.foo_info:
    movl $GHC.Base.const_closure,%ebx
    jmp stg_ap_p_fast
    .size Foo.foo_info, .-Foo.foo_info

;; closure    
.section .data
Foo.foo_closure:
    .quad   Foo.foo_info
    .quad   0
```

The symbols `Foo.foo_info` and `Foo.foo_closure` are exported by the module, and the symbol `Base.const_closure` is referenced by code and data in the model, becoming an undefined symbol that must be resolved.

Another calling module using this `foo` function will typically do so via a reference to the symbol `Foo.foo_closure`.  The linker will resolve the reference from the calling module to the `Foo.foo_closure` label in the `Foo` module, and also resolve the reference from the `Foo` module to the label `GHC.Base.const_closure` in the GHC base package.